# Disable hashchange until scrollling has stopped

Tags: jquery, hashchange

I have a one page site with navigation which allows the user to scroll to the different sections of the page. When the user clicks on a link the hash in the url changes also when the user scrolls the page the hash changes. The only problem I have is if the user is at the top and clicks on the link to go to the footer the hash changes as it skips by the different sections therefore quickly highlighting the navigation links with the selected state before finally reaching the footer. Is there a way I can disable the hashchange function whilst the page is scrolling to the footer?

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(){
   var id = window.location.hash.substring(1);
   $('#header ul li').removeClass('selected');
   $('[data-rel="'+id+'"]').addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: It would help if you can build a little fiddle

Comment: this `$('[data-rel="'+id+'"]')` is mega slow

Comment: so it skips to the clicked section via an animation?

Answer (score 1):

So you should use

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

and run your own code. This should work if I've understood you correctly?

http://jsfiddle.net/FnfgJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is no. If the user want's to change the Hash of the url he will always be able to.
What you can do is disable all the links:

```
$('a').click(function () { return false; }); // disables
$('a').unbind('click'); // enables them again
```